# Unable to mock the component with the given set of mocked data using React Testing Library

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs

This is my component and I am trying to mock method fetchChapterData which would return me the mocked data and would set the state of the component with the returned value but it is not rendering the UI with the mocked data and also re-rendering the component multiple times.

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react'
    import LoadingImg from '../../assets/images/loader.gif'
    import {fetchChapterData} from '../helpers/common'

    class MyComponent extends Component {
        constructor(props){
            super(props)
            this.state={
              isDataLoaded:false
            }
          }
        render() {
            return (
                <div className="abc">
                    {this.state.isDataLoaded?
                        <div className="abc">        
                            <div className="abc" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{__html: this.state.data}}></div>
                        </div>
                    :
                        <div className="loading" key="loading_key">
                            <img src={LoadingImg} alt ="Loading"/>
                        </div>        
                    }    
                </div>
            )
        }
        componentDidMount= async()=> { 
            let result = await fetchChapterData('IntroductionReportChapter')

     /*fetchChapterData is being mocked with data {isDataLoaded:true,data:"<p>hello  all</p>"}*/

            this.setState({...result});
        }
    }

    export default MyComponent;
```

## This is my Test file

so here I am mocking the method fetchChapterData and asking it to return the fake data

```
import React from 'react'
import MyComponent  from './myComponent'
import { render,screen} from "@testing-library/react"
import {fetchChapterData} from '../helpers/common'


jest.mock('../helpers/common', () => ({
  fetchChapterData:jest.fn(),
  }));

let container = document.createElement("div");
document.body.appendChild(container);
const  fakeData={
  "isDataLoaded": true,
  "data":"<p>hello</p>"
  
};

describe("Introduction component testing",  () => {
  
  it('Introduction section rendered or not',async()=>{
    await fetchChapterData.mockResolvedValueOnce({...fakeData})
    render(<MyComponent />)
    await expect(fetchChapterData).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  })
  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

So I got the solution for the same. We need to use the asynchronous version of `act` to apply resolved promises while rendering the component in the test file, and  it would start executing your mocked data.

```
  describe("My component testing",  () => {

  it("renders user data", async () => {
    const fakeData={isDataLoaded:true,intoductionText:" <p>manisha</p>"}
    fetchChapterData.mockResolvedValueOnce({...fakeData})
    await act(async () => {
      render(<MyComponent />, container);
    });
    screen.getByText('manisha')
  });
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Hey – try mocking your data helper like so

```
jest.mock('../helpers/common', () => ({
  fetchChapterData:jest.fn(() => Promise.resolve({
    //Your data here
  }))
}))
```

Also in your state object at the top of the class, you have `false1` instead of `false` do you want to correct that?

You may also want to take another approach to updating the data loaded state property, maybe instead create a helper function in the class that sets that state like so

```
    const handleData = (data) => {
      setState({
          isDataLoaded: true,
          data
      })
    }
```

Finally, call this helper in `componentDidMount` with the result from your `fetchChapterData` function

Comment: So I have given the solution for the same,the thing which I was missing was to use the asynchronous version of act to apply resolved promises while rendering the component in the test file.